# In VB.Net 2008, bound Combo Box doesn't update on move to specific record

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, combobox

I could use some direction as I'm totally stumped on this...

In VB.Net 2008, I have a form with a data binding source called TblComplaintBindingSource. While it had more fields, the two I'm concerned with are lComplaintID (integer and key for the table) and lPersonID which is a key to the Person table.  I have set up a combo box that uses another data binding source QryPersonComboBindingSource.  On my form, I have a combo box cmbPerson defined as:

```
    Me.cmbPerson = New System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Me.cmbPerson.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue",Me.TblComplaintBindingSource, "lPersonID", True))
    Me.cmbPerson.DataSource = Me.QryPersonComboBindingSource
    Me.cmbPerson.DisplayMember = "FullName"
    Me.cmbPerson.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList
    Me.cmbPerson.FormattingEnabled = True
    Me.cmbPerson.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(138, 24)
    Me.cmbPerson.Name = "cmbPerson"
    Me.cmbPerson.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(415, 21)
    Me.cmbPerson.TabIndex = 0
    Me.cmbPerson.ValueMember = "lPersonID"
```

This works fine when I open a record or use the BindingNavigator to move through records, the selected value in the cmbPerson displays correctly.

**HOWEVER**, when I try to open the form and hop to a specific record (by lComplaintID) as a result of a search, the cmbPerson combo box remains stubbornly blank.  Here's my code for jumping to the specific record:

Public Sub OpenSpecificRecord(ByVal vintComplaintID As Integer, ByVal Filter As String)

```
    If Filter = "" Then
        Me.TblComplaintBindingSource.RemoveFilter()
        Me.TblComplaintBindingSource.Filter = "lComplaintID=" & vintComplaintID.ToString()
    Else
        Me.TblComplaintBindingSource.Filter = Filter
    End If
    Me.TblComplaintBindingSource.Find("lComplaintID", vintComplaintID)

    Me.TblComplaintBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem()
    Me.QryPersonComboBindingSource.ResetCurrentItem()
```

This is what the current iteration of the code looks like - I've tried all sorts of tricks to update the SelectedValue of Me.cmbPerson and it stubbornly remains blank.

Any suggestions of where to go?  This is a pretty standard thing I'm trying to do and for the life of me, I have no idea why it doesn't want to update or how to bend it to my will.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: Just a suggestion: use with on your cmbPerson. This way to can get rid of any resources used. For example: With cmbPerson   .DisplayMember = "" then whatever else you want then End With

Comment: While that may be more efficient (I admit, I am using Microsoft's code generation for the objects), it's not my problem.  My problem is occurring as a result of the bottom block of code - I think it's a timing issue - I bound a text box to the same field (lPersonID) and I get a value - just can't get the stupid combo box to display it.